# "Key element does not match the schema" for only one Partition Key with No Sort Keys and No Indexes

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a problem with a DynamoDB table. I only have the partition key with no index and no sort key, yet I still get this Client error when adding rows of data into the Dynamo table. Since I only have one partition key, I am confused as to why I am receiving this error because it looks like the key element (uniqueKey)  **does** match the schema.

> Here is the code (I shortened this for brevity, but I'm simply reading
> rows of CSV file data from a FOR loop and loading the data into a
> DynamoTable):

```
if 'UNIQUE_KEY' in each and each['UNIQUE_KEY'] != 'null' and each['UNIQUE_KEY'] is not None and each['UNIQUE_KEY'] != '':
        dbObj['uniqueKey'] = str(each['UNIQUE_KEY'])
        print('<<uniqueKey>> ', dbObj['uniqueKey']) 
         try:
            response = table.get_item(
            Key={
                'uniqueKey': dbObj['uniqueKey']
                        }
            )
            print(response)
       except ClientError as e:
          print('error message')
          print(e.response['Error']['Message'])`
```

> And here is my table information:

[image]

> Finally: Here is the echo output for the unique Key called uniqueKey
> in the lambda's Cloud Watch debug that I used to show that the Partition key is getting a value:

[image]

> And here is the instantiation of the tables:
> [image]

> Here are the table attributes:
> [image]

Comment: Can you share the output of this statement `print('<<uniqueKey>> ', dbObj['uniqueKey'])`

Comment: Yes  Lee:  I will post it above in the problem description Thanks

Comment: "loading the data" with `get_item`?

Comment: Yes but I feel that has nothing to do with the Key not matching the DynamoDB Table schema. The process should not hit the ClientError exception but instead should bypass that instruction and deal with ultimately putting the item into as table.

Comment: show the code instantiating the client and table.  Also show your table name in it's definition.

Comment: can you show me the output of `table.attribute_definitions()`

Comment: OK Lee . Here are the table attributes.

Comment: I want to see it in JSON format to understand if there is white space before or after the key name. Also print out the value passed to the table name held on your os.environ variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *Lee Hanniga*n  who had me rethink the fact that I may have created the partition Key with a space just after the last character. Once I fixed this , my code worked mostly as expected in that I no longer received the error: **"Key element does not match the schema"**
I now get a few errors on some of the input data but more than half of the CSV file data is reading into the Dynamo Table.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [put_item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) API for adding data in dynamoDB instead of get_item.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

First of all is this python & boto3?  You should mention that and/or include the appropriate tags.

I don't see anything wrong with your `get_item()`, I'd suggest double checking the table name value you've stored in the env variable.

Personally, unless you've got multiple tables with the same structure but a different name, there seems little reason to store the table name in an environment variable.

Lastly, if you're "loading data" and using `get_item()` to check for existence before hand so that you only add new items, you can do that with `put_item` by itself as noted in the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item).

> **Note**
>
> To prevent a new item from replacing an existing item, use a
> conditional expression that contains the attribute_not_exists function
> with the name of the attribute being used as the partition key for the
> table. Since every record must contain that attribute, the
> attribute_not_exists function will only succeed if no matching item
> exists.